# List users not belongs to a role

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-permission

I use laravel spatie package for user permissions. I need to list all users not belongs to a specific user. For example list all non admin(role) users.

For listing all admin users I used

```
$users = App\User::role('admin');
```

I need just opposite to that

Comment: @AdamKozlowski, Other users didn't belong to any role. So I got the result by 


`$users = User::whereDoesntHave('roles')->get();`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try that way:

```
return $this->users()->whereHas('roles', function ($query) {
    return $query->where('name','!=', 'admin');
})->first();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make 2 querys to get both groups of users that you want. I mean:

1 ) Users who don't have any role.

```
User::whereDoesntHave('roles')->count()
```

2 ) Users have any role, but not admin (from Adam Kozlowski answer)

```
$this->users()->whereHas('roles', function ($query) {
    $query->where('name','!=', 'admin');
})->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

As its [documentation](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission) states you can use:

```
$users = User::role('writer')->get(); // Returns only users with the role 'writer'
```

The role scope can accept a string, a \Spatie\Permission\Models\Role object or an \Illuminate\Support\Collection object.

Just put the roles you want to query in a collection.

Answer (score -2):

This fixed it for me

```
$all_roles_except_a_and_b = Role::whereNotIn('name', ['role A', 'role B'])->get();
```

Comment: The question is about listing users with an assigned role, not listing the roles themselves.